# Logic jump and duplication check within the form in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Does Cognito Forms support logic jump and internal duplicity check? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) supports both advanced [Conditional Logic](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/conditional-logic) and [Multi-Page Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/multi-page-forms), which together support skip logic to only show the right pages at the right time.

To implement logic jump with multiple pages, just add page breaks to the form and select "Show Next Page - When" to specify the logic for when a page should be included in the user flow through the form:

[image]

The same conditional logic can be applied to any field, section or [repeating section](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/repeating-sections), allowing you to also implement logic jump on single page forms where this makes sense.  The logic then applies to all printed or emailed views of the form, hiding information and fields that are irrelevant based on the entered information.

I am not entirely certain what the question regarding internal duplicity check refers to.  However, [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) does not currently support form submission restrictions based on IP address or email checks to prevent duplicate submissions, though [spam prevention](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/spam-prevention) is built into every form to block bots.  We do have additional features to block duplicate submissions on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/6jZYx6eV).